# Number sorting with Indexes

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I want sorting Numbers ascending order including their indexes,here i've implemented sorting like this.

```
PriceArray =      [
      " 93",
      " 112.8",
      " 138.45",
      " 127.25",
      " 117.25",
      " 114.45"
    ]
```

by using this,

```
NSArray *myArray = [priceArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:
                            @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"doubleValue"
                                                            ascending:YES]]];
```

After sorting this data came like

```
[
  " 93",
  " 112.8",
  " 114.45",
  " 117.25",
  " 127.25",
  "138.45"
]
```

But i want sorting data including indexes like

```
[
  [
    " 93",
    "0"
  ],
  [
    " 112.8",
    "1"
  ],
  [
    " 114.45",
    "5"
  ],
  [
    " 117.25",
    "4"
  ],
  [
    " 127.25",
    "3"
  ],
  [
    " 138.45",
    "2"
  ]
]
```

Can you please suggest me how can i implement this ? Thank you..

Comment: what is mean by data including indexes..?

Comment: Like Object at Index postions..after sorting @Anbu.Karthik

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't make it any clearer. You have arrays of arrays that you want to sort by 2 keys, a value and and index? You want to add an index value to your sorted results? If you want to add an index value, how is that index value calculated? Only you know what you're trying to achieve, and you're not explaining it well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
NSArray *priceArray =  @[
                   @" 93",
                   @" 112.8",
                   @" 138.45",
                   @" 127.25",
                   @" 117.25",
                   @" 114.45"
                   ];

NSMutableArray *output = [NSMutableArray new];

for(NSInteger i=0;i<[priceArray count];i++){

    NSArray *dataWithIndex = @[priceArray[i],@(i)];
    [output addObject:dataWithIndex];
}

NSArray *sorted = [output sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id  _Nonnull obj1, id  _Nonnull obj2) {

    return [[obj1 firstObject] doubleValue]>[[obj2 firstObject] doubleValue];
}];
NSLog(@"%@",sorted);
```

Comment: i think user needs old index (index before sort).

Comment: Thanks@MaratIbragimov Working for my requirement

Answer (score -1):

```
-(void)getArrayWithIndex:(NSArray *)sortedArray {
NSMutableArray *desiredArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
for (NSString *str1 in sortedArray) {
    NSInteger index = 0;
    for (NSString *str2 in priceArray) {
        if ([str1 isEqualToString:str2]) {
            break;
        }else {
            index++;
        }
    }
    NSArray *tempArray = @[str1,[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",(long)index]];
    [desiredArray addObject:tempArray];
}
NSLog(@"%@",desiredArray);
```

}

Comment: Very Inefficient way of doing it. Also, if a price was identical to another one, you would get the same index returned twice.

Comment: there is taking sorted array as argument and price array has contain without sorting , it means u understand better , before passing argument sort the price array , and then pass it,. no one do spoon feed here , you should understand code. i mentioned clearly sorted array.  And according to question requirement i done best.